# Hibernate + MSSQL Server: using both nvarchar and char strings (jtds driver)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, unicode, jtds

Is it ever possible to use both unicode and non-unicode strings in Hibernate (version 4) and Microsoft SQL server (2008/2012)?

What we have now - customised SQL Server dialect that generate `nvarchar` for strings:

```
public class SQLServerUnicodeDialect extends SQLServerDialect {

    public SQLServerUnicodeDialect(){
        super();

        // Use Unicode Characters
        registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, "nvarchar($l)" );
...
}
```

At jdbc level we're using JTDS driver that convert all strings as unicode by default (see parameter [sendStringParametersAsUnicode](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html)).

So I see 2 problems in the task:

1. How to say hibernate separate unicode and non-unicode strings?
2. Which jdbc driver support both string types (looks like JTDS has 1 option - all strings as unicode or no)?

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: JDBC Version 4 in Java 1.6 added Types.NVARCHAR